# Redirection loop on OVH server

Tags: redirect, ovh

i have a domain on ovh, and so i uploaded all the file via FTP,

but when i want to redirect www.example.com to https://www.example.com/file12345.html it creates a sort of loop which makes i end up on https://www.example.com/file12345.html/file12345.html/file12345.html/file12345.html/file12345.html/file12345.html/file12345.html etc.

I have tried both using the ovh redirection rules and adding an .htaccess file in the root folder with the following code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/file12345.html$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem remains the same. Do you have any solution to that ?